# Azure Database for PostgreSQL fail to Point in time restore

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-database-postgresql

I use Azure Database for PostgreSQL server I can't restore my server it give me the following error

> The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state The
>   user name conflict with an existing database user name is not a valid
>   name because it contains invalid characters.

how to solve that?

Comment: What is the status of your postgreSQL server?  Did you refer to this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-restore-server-portal#point-in-time-restore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , we have to remove AD Internal users as they include '@'  character in username (emails)